# Routing with two different networks at the same time

Tags: networking, routing

I'm not very familiar with routing, but I just want to make sure this is possible because if it was, it would help my home internet a great deal.

Is it possible to make it so, "any application connecting to a specific server in Chicago, will work with network1," and that "any other application connecting anywhere else, excluding the ones connected to network1, will work with network2,"

Alternatively, if I was to block all internet traffic on one router, except for one program, would any of the blocked traffic default to the other network I would be connected to?

Is this possible?

Comment: How many incoming internet lines are there? I mean, what's the application of this question?

Comment: The application I have in mind that would use the specific server in Chicago is a video game called League of Legends, and that would be the only traffic on the first network, and all other traffic would go through the unrelated network2

Comment: Are both networks connected directly to a PC, or to a router? Which operating system is that PC/router running? The capabilities exist in most, but the commands differ a lot.

Comment: @grawity They are both connected to my PC which runs on Windows.